# QGIS viewshed output is null -- incorrect

Tags: qgis, viewshed

I am trying to run a very intensive viewshed in ArcGIS but university power outages are forcing me to use our SCC, which runs on Linux, so I need to use Grass and Q. I am running a much smaller test viewshed as a model for writing the code, and it's frustratingly incorrect. I know what the viewshed output should be -- it runs fine in ArcGIS and I've photographed from each of the OPs.

What I am looking for: a binary, cumulative viewshed with no outer radius, with each OP at a 1.65 m offset. (I realize the outer radius increases the computation, but it's necessary for my research).

What I get: a viewshed output that is completely null

I've checked the imported vector points, the DEM, re-run in ArcGIS, and even applied a small, 200 m radius. Nothing changes the output. I also don't get an error.

Can someone look at these parameters and check to see what I am doing wrong? I am very experienced with ArcGIS, but haven't needed to use Q or Grass very much.

(Apologies for my screen resolution -- GIS programs haven't caught up yet)

[image]